# Bevel automatically applies to new meshes

Tags: mesh, bevel

I started using Blender few days ago to model a space drone.

Everything is going well but I have this issue:

I applied a *Bevel* modifier to the main body of the robot. Since then, every new mesh I create has this weird bevel applied to it. When I create a cube or a cylinder in edit mode, the bevel is applied.... I have no idea how to get rid of this automatic bevel.

[Video](https://youtu.be/Wt1jm-PZ1Io)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! The bevel modifier is applied to the whole object. If you now add more meshes to your object in *Edit Mode*, the modifier will also be applied to these meshes. You would have to add more objects in *Object Mode* instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am following this amazing tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQVdbEOYWE4. For some reason, when Ryan is adding new meshes linked to an object, he doesn't have the issue (e.g. at 53:13).

Comment: as you see at 54:58 the cylinder is bevelled, maybe you need to decrease the width (Amount value) of your Bevel modifier, and also apply the scale of your object? (in Object mode, Ctrl A > Apply Scale)

Comment: Jesus... I am a retard... I put the amount at 0.01. It should have been 0.001. Now it works! I spend 16hrs trying to figure it out... THANKS A LOT EVERYONE!

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As you see at 54:58 the cylinder is also bevelled but the width (*Amount* value) of his *Bevel* modifier is much lower than yours, decrease yours. Also make sure that the scale is applied in *Object* mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*.